# How to retrieve data from Ajax call in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Now that I got my Ajax call to post the email, I'm still struggling trying to retrieve it, validate it, and insert it to my database.

Here is what I've got :

---

## Controller

```
public function postSubscribe() {
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
    }

    dd(json_decode($data));

    // Validation
    $validator = Validator::make( Input::only('subscribe_email'),

        array(

            'subscribe_email' => 'email|unique:subscribes,email',
            )
        );

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('/#footer')
        ->with('subscribe_error','This email is already subscribed to us.')
        ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    }else{

        $subscribe = new Subscribe;
        $subscribe->email = Input::get('subscribe_email');
        $subscribe->save();

        return Redirect::to('/thank-you');

    }
}
```

---

## Route

`Route::post('/subscribe','SubscribeController@postSubscribe');`

Since that a post request, I don't where can I see my  `dd(json_decode($data));` ? Am I doing it right ? Please correct me.

---

## Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/subscribe', 'class' => 'subscribe-form', 'role' =>'form')) !!}

<div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-1">
  <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="subscribe_email" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email" required>

  <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_168a366a98d3248fbc35c0b67_73d49e0d23" value=""></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

  <button type="button" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

## Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscribe').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
      url: '/subscribe',
      type: "post",
      data: {'subscribe_email':$('input[name=subscribe_email]').val(), '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
      dataType: 'JSON',

      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      } // this is good

    });
   });
  });

</script>
```

---

## Posting data successfully

[image]

---

## Questions

How do I debug something like that on my own in the future ?
What is the most practical way to retrieve data from Ajax call in PHP Laravel ?

Comment: You posted a screenshot of headers, switch the tab to respone or preview. Also, you shouldnt have to decode the $data

Comment: You're right ! I shouldn't decode it. Plus after changing it to encode, it work s, and changing the tab to response, I see it what I post now.

Comment: As far as how to debug something like this, find an IDE which will allow you to make web requests and step through your code line by line.  It can save you tons of time when you are stuck on something.

Comment: Is there anything you know in Sublime Text ? I use sublime text 3 right now.

Comment: They do have an xdebug plugin but last I tried it, it didn't seem to work that great.  Some people I work with use NetBeans and claim it's pretty good for stepping through code and is free.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for something similar to that in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to @Pawel Bieszczad

change : `dd(json_decode($data));`

to : `dd(json_encode($data));`

---

and open up **console** > **Network Tab** > **Response**

Now I see my response as expected.

`"{"subscribe_email":"bheng@outlook.com","_token":"S3lWmNn6gkkHrYY6nPmupCtrlRqWF6au7b0Mywy7"}"`

Comment: not convenient way. Having one function for dumping everything would be more useful when setting up  live template